# Is it possible to send notifications to Firebase using PHP that targets user segments instead of topics?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get my webview apps working with Firebase, but the iOS apps aren't subscribing to the topic they're supposed to be.  So they don't receive FCM notifications. (Androids are fine.) However, inside the FCM message composer, you can select the iOS app I have set up under "User Segment", and the iOS devices do receive the notification.  So I'm wondering if there is a way to target that user segment instead of using a topic.

[screenshot of my FCM message composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFjm0.png)

I haven't tried anything yet. I need information.

Comment: There is no API to send message to user segments through FCM. The functionality for that is only available in the Firebase console.

Comment: Not sure why this was marked as a duplicate. All the answers to the other questions listed are from at least 4 years ago. A lot has changed since then. Any other current answers?

Comment: While many things have changed, there is still no API to send messages to a user segment. The functionality is still only available in the Firebase console.

Comment: Probably could've just said that instead of giving no explanation and just marking it as a duplicate.  Everything else has changed since 4 years ago.  Those of us who haven't been doing this for 4 years may not know this.

Comment: Just like you could've said that you'd seen those answers and were wondering if anything changed in the meantime. But I'm glad we got it clear in the end, Jason.